# Update only div with setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am trying to update a table every certain time with a setinterval and if the table is updated, the problem is that the whole page is updated and also doubles, this is an example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>hello</h1>

  <div id="updategreeting">
    <h2>hello2</h2>
  </div>

</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(

      function() {
        $("#updategreeting").empty().load("#updategreeting");
      }, 10000

    );
  });
</script>
```

when executing in the navigator it is shown (**hello hello2**) but when recharging with the set interval it will show (**hello hello hello2**)

and then if I just want to update the div (updategreeting) and not load the (hello), I hope you can help me thanks.

Comment: you have to deal with the load callback, or use promise

Comment: There is all sorts of thing wrong in this code, but why do you think that `.empty()`, to clear out the source, and then `.load()` to load from the empty source would do anything other than provide and empty result?